# RPi.GPIO This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi! VIRTUAL RPiOS

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, virtualbox, gpio

is it possible to run script with Python using RPi.GPIO on virtual Raspbian OS? I installed the newest Raspberry OS in VirtualBox but if I want to run the script I get error "This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!" Is there any option to run it even if it's not running on real Raspberry? The reason I use VirtualBox is that I'm testing stuff in that and if it works fine then run it on real Raspberry. Thanks

Comment: You are running the Raspberry Pi OS for Desktop in a VirtualBox on the PC? That is (except for the look-and-feel) _very_ different from the OS on the real pi and hardly useful for the purpose you intend it for.

Comment: @PMF Yes, I have installed Pi OS for Desktop. So do you think if I'll install version for RPi it could work? And is it even possible to install RPi version on virtualbox which has nothing common to real RPi ?

Comment: No, that won't work either. I think you could use something like qemu, but I'm not sure how that behaves when it comes to real hardware. I guess you want to attach something to the gpio pins. Why don't you just use the real pi?